# Self-hosted WCF REST service and Basic authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication, rest, basic-authentication, wcf-rest-contrib

I've created a self-hosted WCF REST service (with some extra's from WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2). This is all working fine.

I'm now trying to add Basic authentication to the service. But I'm hitting some rather large roadblocks in the WCF stack which is preventing me from doing this.

It appears that the `HttpListener` (which self-hosted WCF services use internally at a low level in the WCF stack) is blocking my attempts to insert a `WWW-Authenticate` header on a self-generated `401 Unauthorized` response. Why?

I can get the authentication working if I forget about this `WWW-Authenticate` header (which it seems Microsoft did as well). But that's the issue. If I don't send back a `WWW-Authenticate` header then the web browser won't display its standard "logon" dialog. The user will merely be faced with a `401 Unauthorized` error page with no way to actually log on.

REST services should be accessible to both computers and humans (well at least on the GET request level). Therefore, I feel that WCF REST is not complying with a fundamental part of REST here. Does anyone agree with me?

Has anyone got Basic authentication working with a self-hosted WCF REST service? If so, how did you do it?

PS: Obviously my intentions to use unsecure Basic authentication are on the premise that I'd also get HTTPS/SSL working for my service too. But that's another matter.

PPS: I've tried WCF REST Contrib (http://wcfrestcontrib.codeplex.com/) and that has exactly the same issue. It appears this library has not been tested in self-hosted scenarios.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately I have determined (by analysing the WCF reference source code and the help of the Fiddler tool for HTTP session sniffing) that this is a bug in the WCF stack.

Using Fiddler, I noticed that my WCF service was behaving unlike any other web site which uses Basic authentication.

To be clear, this is what SHOULD happen:

1. Browser sends `GET` request with no knowledge that a password is even needed.
2. Web server rejects request with a `401 Unauthorized` status and includes a `WWW-Authenticate` header containing information about acceptable authentication methods.
3. Browser prompts user to enter credentials.
4. Browser resends `GET` request and includes appropriate `Authentication` header with the credentials.
5. If the credentials were correct, the web server responds with `200 OK` and the web page.
   If the credentials were wrong, the web server responds with `401 Unauthorized` and includes the same `WWW-Authenticate` header that it did in Step #2.

What was ACTUALLY happening with my WCF service was this:

1. Browser sends `GET` request with no knowledge that a password is even needed.
2. WCF notices there is no `Authentication` header in the request and blindly rejects request with a `401 Unauthorized` status and includes a `WWW-Authenticate` header. All normal so far.
3. Browser prompts user for credentials. Still normal.
4. Browser resends `GET` request including the appropriate `Authentication` header.
5. If the credentials were correct, the web server responds with `200 OK`. All is fine.
   If the credentials were wrong however, WCF responds with `403 Forbidden` and does not include any additional headers such as `WWW-Authenticate`.

When the browser gets the `403 Forbidden` status it does not perceive this to be a failed authentication attempt. This status code is intended to inform the browser that the URL it tried to access is off limits. It doesn't relate to authentication in any way. This has the terrible side affect that when the user types their username/password incorrectly (and the server rejects with 403) then the web browser doesn't reprompt the user to type their credentials again. In fact the web browser believes authentication has succeeded and so stores those credentials for the rest of the session!

With this in mind, I sought clarification:

The RFC 2617 (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2617.html#ixzz0eboUfnrl) does not mention anywhere the use of the `403 Forbidden` status code. In fact, what it actually has to say on the matter is the following:

> If the origin server does not wish to
>   accept the credentials sent with a
>   request, it SHOULD return a 401
>   (Unauthorized) response. The response
>   MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header
>   field containing at least one
>   (possibly new) challenge applicable to
>   the requested resource.

WCF does neither of these. It neither correctly sends an `401 Unauthorized` status code. Nor does it include a `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Now to find the smoking gun within the WCF source code:

I discovered that in the `HttpRequestContext` class is a method called `ProcessAuthentication`, which contains the following (excerpt):

```
if (!authenticationSucceeded) 
{
   SendResponseAndClose(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
}
```

I defend Microsoft on a lot of things but this is indefensible.

Fortunately, I have got it working to an "acceptable" level. It just means that if the user accidently enters their username/password incorrectly then the only way to get another attempt is to fully close their web browser and restart it to retry. All because WCF is *not* responding to the failed authentication attempt with a `401 Unauthorized` and a `WWW-Authenticate` header as per the specification.

Comment: @serialseb I didn't have the heart to tell him that I gave up on trying to solve auth issues on WCF and went straight to HttpListener directly.

Comment: Cheers guys :) Darrel, I did see your comments in another discussion and believe me I have considered that as an option. Luckily we have not invested too much in WCF REST yet. So we may go ahead and ditch it.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution based in this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/531787/self-hosted-wcf-rest-with-http-basic-authentication) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2010/02/02/fix-to-allow-customizing-the-status-code-when-validation-fails.aspx).

The first is to override the method Validate in a class called **CustomUserNameValidator** wich inherits from **System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator**:

```
Imports System.IdentityModel.Selectors
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Net

Public Class CustomUserNameValidator
    Inherits UserNamePasswordValidator

Public Overrides Sub Validate(userName As String, password As String)
    If Nothing = userName OrElse Nothing = password Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException()
    End If

    If Not (userName = "user" AndAlso password = "password") Then
        Dim exep As New AddressAccessDeniedException("Incorrect user or password")
        exep.Data("HttpStatusCode") = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
        Throw exep
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

The trick was change the attribute of the exception "HttpStatusCode" to HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

The second is create the **serviceBehavior** in the App.config as follows:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HttpEnableBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Service.CustomUserNameValidator, Service"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Finally we must to specify the configuration for the webHttpBinding and apply it to the endpoint:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicAuthBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm=""/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<service behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior" name="Service.webService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/webService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/webService/restful" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicAuthBinding" contract="Service.IwebService" behaviorConfiguration="HttpEnableBehavior"/>
</service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can provide Basic authentication for REST based WCF services. However there are several steps which you must follow to have a ***complete and secure solution*** and thus far most responses are fragments of all the pieces needed.

1. Configure your self-hosted service to have a SSL certificate bound to the port which you are hosting your WCF service on. This is very different than applying a SSL cert when using managed hosting through something like IIS. You have to apply the SSL certificate using a command line utility. You **DO NOT** want to use Basic Authentication on a REST service *without* using SSL because the credentials in the header on not secure. Here are (2) detailed posts that I wrote on *exactly* how to do this. Your question is too big to have all the details on a forum post, so that is why I am providing the links with comprehensive details and step by step instructions:

   [Applying and Using a SSL Certificate With A Self-Hosted WCF Service](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/02/applying-and-using-ssl-certificate-with.html)

   [Creating a WCF RESTful Service And Secure It Using HTTPS Over SSL](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/05/creating-wcf-restful-service-and-secure.html)
2. Configure your service to use Basic authentication. This is a multi-part solution as well. 1st is configuring your service to use Basic authentication. The second is to create a 'customUserNamePasswordValidatorType' and inspect the credentials to *authenticate* the client. I see the last post eluded to this, however it did **not** use HTTPS and is only 1 very small part of the solution; be careful of guidance that does *not* provided an end-to-end solution inclusive of configuration *and* security. The last step is to look at the security context to provide authorization at the method level if needed. The following post I wrote takes you step-by-step on how to configure, authenticate, *and* authorize your clients.

   [RESTful Services: Authenticating Clients Using Basic Authentication](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/06/restful-services-authenticating-clients.html)

This is the end-to-end solution needed for using Basic Authentication with self-hosted WCF services.